# AndroidError : Program type already present : android_serialport_api.SerialPort when I try generate Signed APK from Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, aar

I am getting specified exception after adding .aar file to app gradle:Program type already present: android_serialport_api.SerialPort

When I try to build Debug APK it is working but When I try to build Signed APK it is giving specified exception

Below is my app-gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XX.XX.XX"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 27
        versionName "6.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3';
        all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio';
    }
   
}

repositories {
    maven { url "jitpack.io" }
    maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')

    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.11.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.54'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'

    /*implementation(name: 'merchantsdk', ext: 'aar')*/
    /*implementation(name: 'merchantsdk', ext: 'aar'){
        exclude module: 'SerialPort'
    }*/
    /*implementation(name: 'ezetapandroidsdk', ext: 'aar')*/

    implementation project(':merchantsdk')
    implementation project(':ezetapandroidsdk')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is the Project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"}
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is the exception

```
  > Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android_serialport_api.a","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

Debug apk is working fine but when I try to build signed APK giving above exception.
Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that there are 2 or more packages using `android_serialport_api.SerialPort`. Where does `merchantsdk` come from?

Comment: Thanks for your response HB, its an third party SDK for our Project, How to check the duplicacy of packages ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have more that one package using `android_serialport_api.SerialPort`.

There is 2 ways of dealing with this. The first is going through each library and checking if it's using it or you can find duplicates by running:

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

You can also exclude it from your `merchantsdk`, like this:

```
implementation(name: 'merchantsdk', ext: 'aar'){
    exclude module: 'SerialPort'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried with the 2nd option still the same exception is coming.Could you please help me on this.